# Use sshfs simultaneously with multiple users

Tags: nfs, sshfs

Please consider the following scenario:

- Three machines: server S1, client C1 (Linux), client C2 (Windows)
- An NFS file system that can only be accessed from the server's local subnet
- The NFS volume is mounted to `/mnt/foo` on S1 as user `ubuntu`
- I'd like enable the clients to (occasionally) access the NFS volume
- One option would be to set up a VPN, but I'd prefer to use `sshfs` instead

The clients could connect doing `sshfs ubuntu@s1:/mnt/foo /mnt/bar/` (or using [sshfs-win](https://github.com/winfsp/sshfs-win) on the Windows machine) and with `-o idmap=user` I can probably sort the file permissions.

So the setup will be:

```
Client -> sshfs -> Server -> NFS -> Storage
```

My question is: are there any concerns related to multiple users (C1 and C2, potentially also S1 itself) accessing files simultaneously. Will file locking, etc. still work with this setup?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please add the following information to your question. Which distro and version of Linux are you using? What are the exact error messages you get when you try this? This site is not good for hypothetical scenarios.

Comment: File locking is typically application-specific and has little to do with modern file systems or their abstraction layers 

Comment: So you don't see any potential issues with this setup?